# Where to post non programming but computer software installation questions

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question related to trouble in installing and running a software. I believe Stack Overflow is only for programming? Is that correct?

If so, where do I post software installation question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Super User](http://superuser.com):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking

Comment: Thanks mate @animuson